# Change border width

Tags: css, border

So i've been searching a lot lately and cant find an answer. How do I change the width of a border-bottom like I want to have it 5px from left to right, How?
I tried watchin[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzBA7.jpg)g youtube videos and everything

As you can see in the picture the border bottom's width is not 100% to the text

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Mohammed Mustafa Can you provide us the example of what exactly you want to achieve and where exactly are you trying to add border width?

Comment: I mean `border-bottom-width: 5px` might work, but will need to see your code to know.

Comment: A border - by design - will take the full length of the element; it can't be offset by any amount. If you share your (required) "*[mcve]*" code then we may be able to offer alternatives.

Comment: @Hypermystic Please check the picture I added to the post, Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nice effect of drawing fake border using background width. You can very much play with size, color width and so on.

```css
a {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-size: 0 1px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 100%;
  transition: background-size .5s ease-out;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 20%, currentColor 21%);
}

a:hover {
  background-size: 100% 1px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Hover me with your mouse</a>
```